What algorithm will perform this matrix decomposition?
I am new to the algorithms of matrix decomposition and I am looking for a way to perform it on this matrix (see Fig 1).
I would like one of the factors to be a particular matrix (see Fig 2), and I do not care what are the contents of the other one.
Based on their dimensions, I believe I need a 20 x 7 matrix, since the original is 20 x 48 and the one factor I care about is 7 x 48, so the other factor needs to be 20 x 7 matrix in order to convert them back to the original matrix through the dot product.
Thank you!
Fig 1:
A 20-row X 48-column matrix:
000000000000 000000000000 000100000100 000100000100
000000000000 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000
000000000000 000000000000 100100100100 100100100100

000000000000 000000000000 100010100010 100010100010
000000000000 000000000100 010001010001 010001010001

000000000000 000000100100 001000001000 001000001000
000000000000 000000000010 000000000000 000000000000
000000000000 000100100001 000000000000 000000000000

000000000000 000100010000 000000000000 000000000000
000000000000 100010001000 000000000000 000000000000

000000000100 100001000000 000000000000 000000000000
000000000000 010000000000 000000000000 000000000000
000000100100 001000000000 000000000000 000000000000

000000100010 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000
000100010001 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000

100100001000 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000
000010000000 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000
000001000000 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000

000000000000 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000
000000000000 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000

Fig 2:
A 7-row by 48-column matrix
000000000000 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000
000000000000 100000000000 000000000000 000000000000

000000000100 000000100000 000100000100 000000000000
000000000000 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000
000000100000 000100000000 100000100000 100000000000

000000000000 000000000100 000000000000 000000000000
000100000000 000000000000 000000000000 000000000000

